# PDF of area of triangle with normally-distributed coordinates in any dimensions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, triangles, simplex, geometric-probability

#### Question

**What is the probability distribution function (PDF) of the absolute area of a triangle with normally-distributed coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^m$ $(m \in \mathbb{N}, m\ge2)$ ? A conjecture is given that can be proved or might help to find the correct solution.**

The triangle vertices in $\mathbb{R}^m$  are
$$ \mathbf{\mathrm{X}_1} =(x_1^1,\ldots, x_1^m),\;\;   \mathbf{\mathrm{X}_2}=(x_2^1,\ldots,x_2^m),\;\;    \mathbf{\mathrm{X}_3}=(x_3^1,\ldots,x_3^m)$$
where $x_i^j$ are independent standard normal distributed variables
$$x_i^j\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
The non-oriented area $A$ of a random triangle instance in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is
$$A=\|\mathbf{\mathrm{X}_1}-\mathbf{\mathrm{X}_3}\|\, \|\mathbf{\mathrm{X}_2}-\mathbf{\mathrm{X}_3}\| \frac{\sin\alpha}{2}\tag{1}$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm and $\alpha$ is the angle at $\mathbf{\mathrm{X}_3}$. The expectation value of $A$  is
$$\mathbb{E}[A]=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(m-1\right)\tag{2}$$
A proof of eq.(2) can be found in this Cross Validated [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448294/269684).

#### Conjecture for PDF

The probability distribution of empirical data of $A$ for any tested $m$ can be fitted quite well with the function
$$f(A)=\frac{k^{m-1}} {A \mathrm{e}^k (m-2)! }\, \, \text{
with} \, \ k=\frac{2A}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{3}$$

that fulfills also the conditions of a PDF
$$\int_0^\infty f(A) \mathrm{d}A=1\ \,\, \text{and}\ \int_0^\infty A f(A)\mathrm{d}A=\mathbb{E}[A]$$

Experimental data is indistinguishable from eq.(3) but a proof is missing.

#### Related question

In a similar case the PDF for the volume of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ was tried to solve in this Math SE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4067230/737314) but no full solution was given so far.

Comment: Have you already worked out, or are you interested in, the case of $m=2$, and also the case when one coordinate is fixed, say, at the origin?

Comment: Also, it says in the attached post that for $n=3$ the distribution is $\Gamma$ and for larger $n$ it is related to a Bessel K distribution. Your density reveals itself to be a Gamma as well.

Comment: of course a partial solution would also be of interest, that might help to find the complete solution

Answer (score 7):

Concerning a *triangle with a vertex at the origin* , thus a parallelogram defined by two vectors,
or otherwise the modulus of their cross-product, an answer for the case 3D has been already
provided in my answer to [the related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056138) on the PDF of the volume of a tetrahedron, which is
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Pr \left( {\left| {{\bf a} \times {\bf b}} \right| \in \left[ {c,c + dc} \right)} \right)
 = p_c (c)dc\quad \left| \matrix{
  \,{\bf a},{\bf b} \sim \left( {{\cal N}_1 \,} \right)^{\,3}  \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le c \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = {2 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}cdc
\int_{v = 0}^\infty  {e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\left( {v^{\,2}  + c^{\,2} /v^{\,2} } \right)} \,dv}  =   \cr 
  &  = c\,e^{\, - \,\,c} dc
\quad  \Rightarrow \quad p_c (c) = \Gamma _{\,2,\,1} (c) \cr} 
$$

The derivation employed there can be extended to $m$-D as follows.

The density in  the $m$-space reads as
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{p_p} _m} ({\bf V})dV =
 \,\left( {{\cal N}_{\sigma ^{\,2} } \,(x_{\,1} ){\cal N}_{\sigma ^{\,2} } \,(x_{\,1} )
 \cdots {\cal N}_{\sigma ^{\,2} } \,(x_{\,m} )} \right)\,dx_{\,1} \,dx_{\,2} \, \cdots dx_{\,m}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)^{\,m} e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}
 \left( {{r \over \sigma }} \right)^{\,2} } \,dA_{\,m - 1} (r)\,dr =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)^{\,m} e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\left( {{r \over \sigma }}
 \right)^{\,2} } \,dA_{\,m - 1} (r/\sigma )\,d(r/\sigma ) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)^{\,m} e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\rho ^{\,2} } \,dA_{\,m - 1}
 (\rho )\,d\rho  \cr} 
$$
with the surface of a $m-1$-sphere (in a $m$- space) being
$$
A_{\,m - 1} (\rho ) =
 {{2\pi ^{\,{m \over 2}} }
 \over {\Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)}}
\rho ^{\,m - 1} 
$$
and $dA_{m-1}(r)$indicating an elementary surface on the sphere of constant radius $r$.

So, taking  a unitary variance and using $r$ for simplicity, upon integrating over the surface at constant $r$ we get
$$
\eqalign{
  &{{ p_r} _m} (r)dr =
 \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)^{\,m} {{2\pi ^{\,{m \over 2}} }
 \over {\Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)}}
 r^{\,m - 1} e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}r^{\,2} } \,\,dr =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{{m \over 2} - 1} \Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)}}
r^{\,m - 1} e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}r^{\,2} } \,\,dr = \chi _m \,(r)\,dr \cr} 
$$
as it shall be.

Let's pass to the "cross-product" of two vectors ${\bf a}, \, {\bf b}$ having such a spherical distribution.
In the $m$-D space we generalize the cross product by the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivector)
whose modulus can be written as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left| {\,{\bf a} \wedge {\bf b}\,} \right|
 = \left| {\,{\bf a}\,} \right|\left| {\,{\bf b}\,} \right|\sin \left( {\angle {\bf a},{\bf b}} \right)
 = \left| {\,{\bf a}\,} \right|\left| {\,{\bf b}_{\, \bot {\bf a}} \,} \right|  \cr 
  &  = a\sqrt {b^{\,2}  - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {{\bf a} \over a}} \right)^{\,2} }
  = \sqrt {a^{\,2} b^{\,2}  - \left( {{\bf b} \cdot {\bf a}} \right)^{\,2} }  \cr} 
$$
with a clear meaning of the symbols, i.e.

> the area of the parallelogram defined by ${\bf a},\, {\bf b}$.

We fix the first to have modulus $\left[ {a,a + da} \right)$.
Then all the vectors which have a contant wedge-product modulus $\left[{c, c+dc}\right)$ with that will be those which end into a
cylindrical circular shell around $\bf a$, with radius $\left[ {c/a, c/a+dc/a}\right)$.
In the axial direction they are ${\mathcal N}_1$ distributed, and integrating over that  their probability sums to

$$
\chi _{m - 1} \,(c/a)\,dc/a
$$
Therefore we obtain
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \Pr \left( {\left| {{\bf a} \wedge {\bf b}} \right| \in \left[ {c,c + dc} \right)} \right)
 = {{p_c} _m} (c)dc\quad \left| \matrix{
  \,{\bf a},{\bf b} \sim \left( {{\cal N}_1 \,} \right)^{\,m}  \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le c \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_a {\chi _m \,(a)\,da\,\chi _{m - 1} \,(c/a)\,dc/a\,}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{a = 0}^\infty
  {{{a^{\,m - 1} } \over {2^{\,m/2 - 1} \Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)}}e^{\, - \,a^{\,2} /2} \,da
  {{\left( {c/a} \right)^{\,m - 2} } \over {2^{\,m/2 - 3/2} \Gamma \left( {{{m - 1} \over 2}} \right)}}
  e^{\, - \,\left( {c/a} \right)^{\,2} /2} \,dc/a\,}  =   \cr 
  &  = dc{{c^{\,m - 2} } \over {2^{\,m - 5/2} \Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)
  \Gamma \left( {{{m - 1} \over 2}} \right)}}
  \int_{a = 0}^\infty
  {\,e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\left( {a^{\,2}  + {{c^{\,2} } \over {a^{\,2} }}} \right)} da\,}  =   \cr 
  &  = dc{{c^{\,m - 2} } \over {2^{\,m - 5/2} \Gamma \left( {{m \over 2}} \right)
  \Gamma \left( {{{m - 1} \over 2}} \right)}}\sqrt {{\pi  \over 2}} \,e^{\, - \,\,\sqrt {c^{\,2} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = dc{{c^{\,m - 2} } \over {{{2^{\,2\left( {{{m - 1} \over 2}} \right) - 1} } \over {\sqrt \pi  }}
  \Gamma \left( {{{m - 1} \over 2} + {1 \over 2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {{{m - 1} \over 2}} \right)}}\,
  e^{\, - \,\,\sqrt {c^{\,2} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = dc{{c^{\,m - 2} } \over {\;\Gamma \left( {m - 1} \right)}}\,e^{\, - \,\,c}
  = \Gamma _{\,m - 1,\,1} (c)\,dc \cr} 
}$$
which, as far as the simulation on my computer can go, **checks**.

> Same as per the previous post, it remains to work out the case in
> which the parallelogram is translated from the origin.
> The simulations indicates that it is  $\Gamma _{\,m - 1,\,1} (c/ \sqrt{3}) =\Gamma _{\,m - 1,\,\sqrt{3}} (c) $
> but could not reach yet to prove that.
> This would give in fact an expected value $E\left[ c \right] = \left( {m - 1} \right)\sqrt 3 $
> for the parallelogram, which corresponds to the value you cite for the triangle,
> and confirms your fitting formula.

Comment: thanks for the bounty: I am continuing to work  on the "translated" case